# Taking a picture with metadata from Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have a camera connected to my computer and I want to take a picture, when a person is detected. Up to here everything works fine with Python and OpenCV. But I would also like to capture the metadata. Is there any possibility to do so?

Comment: not from opencv. if you use VideoCapture, all metadata will get discarded before you can get to it.

Comment: What do you mean by metadata?